# R, join within a range vectorised

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, sqldf

I'm trying to join two datasets where a variable (or position along a genome) in one dataset fits within a range in the second (gene start/stop position). However, positions are not unique, but nested within an additional column (chromosome). The same goes for the gene start/stop positions. My goal is to link each position with the corresponding annotation and effect.

For example:

```
library(sqldf)
set.seed(100)
a <- data.frame(
    annotation = sample(c("this", "that", "other"), 3, replace=TRUE),
    start = seq(1, 30, 10),
    chr = sample(1:3, 3, replace=TRUE)
  )
a$stop <- a$start + 10
b <- data.frame(
    chr = sample(1:3, 3, replace=TRUE),
    position = sample(1:15, 3, replace=TRUE),
    effect = sample(c("high", "low"), 3, replace=TRUE)
  )
```

An SQL inner join gets me part of the way there:

```
df<-sqldf("SELECT a.start, a.stop, a.annotation, b.effect, b.position
    FROM a, b
    inner JOIN a b on(b.position >= a.start and b.position <= a.stop);")
```

But this doesn't account for the repetition of position per chromosome. 
I'm having conceptual trouble wrapping this into a loop or apply function.

I'm not wedded to SQL, it's just how I tackled a simpler problem previously. I'm also not sure that making an additional index column is appropriate since I have thousands of chromosome values.

My desired output would look like the following:

```
    df$chr<-c("NA","2","2")
      start stop annotation effect position chr
1     1   11       this   high        3  NA
2     1   11       this   high       10  NA
3    11   21       this    low       14   2
```

Where each `position` has been placed between the `start` and `stop` points on the correct `chr`, or given `NA` where no points on a `chr` match.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the set.seed when I re-ran the code. The chr column is dummy data I've appended just to show what I'm after. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @smm sorry but I still don't understand what's going on - the `chr` column in desired result is mysterious - I don't understand its relationship with `a$chr` and `b$chr`

Comment: thanks @eddi The 'position','start' and 'stop' are nested within the 'chr' number, so it should be common across both datasets.

Comment: @smm what is the origin of e.g. lines 1:3 in `df`, i.e. how do you get them from `a` and `b`?

Comment: @eddi "df" line 2 takes a "position" of 3 from from "b", locates it between the "start"/"stop" of "a" and links the "annotation" and "effect" information. Fine as it is but I need to repeat this process independently for each "chr" value. Sorry if I'm not making this clear.

Comment: @smm the `chr` column is the part that I don't understand - where are those repeated 3, 1, 2 coming from?

Comment: @eddi My fault- I just made up the data for the `chr` column. Fixed now. The first three would be NA as the position doesn't map to the correct chromosome.

Comment: @smm why are there 3 identical rows repeated for each position?

Comment: @eddi I think it's something going wrong with my sql query. I don't need the repeats but haven't been able to get around that yet.

Comment: @Gregor Apologies, hopefully clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
sqldf(
    "Select start, stop, annotation, effect, position,
    case when a.chr = b.chr then a.chr else NULL end as chr
    from b left join a
    on b.position between a.start and a.stop
    "
)
#   start stop annotation effect position chr
# 1     1   11       this   high        3  NA
# 2     1   11       this   high       10  NA
# 3    11   21       this    low       14   2
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was after. I'll change the `chr` desired output for the sake of future readers. That was painful for you and @eddi, but it's helped me out. I'll make sure my future posts don't require telepathy.

Answer (score 4):

The [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table` introduces non-equi joins, allowing for:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a) # converting to data.table in place
setDT(b)

b[a, on = .(position >= start, position <= stop), nomatch = 0,
  .(start, stop, annotation, effect, x.position, chr = ifelse(i.chr == x.chr, i.chr, NA))]
#   start stop annotation effect x.position chr
#1:     1   11       this   high          3  NA
#2:     1   11       this   high         10  NA
#3:    11   21       this    low         14   2
```

Comment: That's an exciting data.table development!

Comment: Thanks @eddi, I realise now my desired output was incoherent. This is great though- I'll check out data.table again. Thanks for taking the time on this question- this answer would work if I then subset on the `chr` column.